# Performance issue while listing statements of an inferred model

Tags: jena, semantic-web, owl, reasoning

I am developing an application using Apache Jena to work with RDF triples and OWL ontologies.

**The problem**

What I am currently trying to do is to get a model from a TDB triplestore, to infer on this model and to find some statements in the inferred model. This is done thanks to the `StmtIterator listStatements(Resource s, Property p, RDFNode o)` method. And then a really simple `while(iter.hasNext())` loop is made to iterate over the statements.

At first glance, it seems to work well but it is really slow.
For my reasonably small model, it takes approximately 5 minutes while it takes only a few milliseconds on the (not inferred) model.

**An example with the Pizza ontology**

In this example, I am using the Pizza ontology available [here](http://protege.stanford.edu/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl). The code looks like :

```
public class TestInferedModel {

    private static final String INPUT_FILE_NAME = "path/to/file";
    private static final String URI = "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/pizza.owl#";

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestInferedModel.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
        model.read(INPUT_FILE_NAME);

        Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();   
        reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema(model);

        Model infmodel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, model);

        logger.debug("Model size : " + model.size() + " and inferred model size : " + infmodel.size()); 
        // prints Model size : 2028 and inferred model size : 4881

        StmtIterator iter = infmodel.listStatements();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {  // <----- Performance issue seems to come from this line
            // Operations with the next statement
            Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
            logger.info(stmt);
        }

        model.close();
    }
}
```

Here, the model size is approximately two thousands triples while the inferred model is made of a bit less than five thousands triples. However, running the code above takes much more time than running the same piece of code after editing `StmtIterator iter = infmodel.listStatements();` to `StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements();`. Plus, when trying to add parameters to restrict the statements, the program seems to be running in an infinite loop.

I tried to add a couple of `logger.debug()` message to see where the program is wasting so much time and it seems that the issue comes from the `while(iter.hasNext())` line.

**The question**

I thought the `listStatements()` method is of polynomial (or linear) complexity, not exponential, isn't it ? Is it normal that it takes so much time for the inferred model ? How can I avoid that ?

I'd like to be able to list statements and to manipulate the inferred model without requiring the user to wait ten minutes for an answer...

This issue seems similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181183/jena-how-to-infer-data-performance-issues). However the answer is not really helping me to understand.